# How do I call API on angular dom, given that API calls on plain nativescript is working?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

fails inside the library, [inside the prototype method](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-periscopehearts/blob/0c9acb1b3a15d139ecd30f9bcb9e1371ae660198/periscopehearts.android.ts#L18) in tns_modules, `this._android` is undefined I guess.

`_createUI()` never seem to have got called.

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addHeart' of undefined
>   File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng210June/files/app/tns_modules//bundles/core.umd.js, line: 13024, column: 8
>
> StackTrace:
>   Frame: function:'PeriscopeHearts.addHeart', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng210June/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-periscopehearts/periscopehearts.js', line: 19, column: 22
>   Frame: function:'WebRtcViewComponent.newHeart', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng210June/files/app/modules/webrtcview/webrtcview.component.js', line: 39, column: 24
>   Frame: function:'', file:'', line: 81, column: 24
>   Frame: function:'handleEvent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng210June/files/app/tns_modules//bundles/core.umd.js', line: 11805, column: 138

The calling code is this:

```
  @ViewChild('heartLayout') heartLayout_el: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.peri_heart_el_native = <PeriscopeHearts>(this.heartLayout_el.nativeElement);
    alert('this.peri_heart_el_native:' + this.peri_heart_el_native); //PeriscopeHearts(771)
  }
  newHeart() {
    let colorArray = [{ hex: "#3489db" }, { hex: '#FF4081' }, { hex: '#229911' }, { hex: '#fff000' }];
    let rand = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    this.peri_heart_el_native.addHeart(rand.hex);
  }
```

and the template:

```
<side-drawer-page>
  <StackLayout class="coverImage">
    <Button text="Add Heart" (tap)="newHeart()"></Button>
    <PeriscopeHearts #heartLayout class="heartLayout" height="400">
    </PeriscopeHearts>
  </StackLayout>
</side-drawer-page>
```

PS: a github issue on [plugin](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-periscopehearts/issues/3) has been created but it's more of an angular issue than specific to plugin so replicated here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `loaded` event to grab the references to `heartLayout`

e.g.

```
onLoaded(args) {
   this.peri_heart_el_native = <PeriscopeHearts>args.object;
}
```

in your HTML

```
<PeriscopeHearts (loaded)="onLoaded($event)" class="heartLayout" height="400">
```